# hls.js disable rewind but allow timeshift

Tags: javascript, http-live-streaming, hls.js

I'm looking for a set of [hls.js configuration](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/blob/master/docs/API.md#fine-tuning) options that will allow the following:

1. Start playback of live in latest moment of live broadcast. Ie. live is on for 30 minutes now, *I joined – I see 30min and can watch further.*
2. Once I started watching in 30min *I cannot rewind to a random moment in the past 30 minutes*.
3. But *I can pause the broadcast so when I continue playback, I'll be able to continue watching from where I left*.

If it won't be possible to achieve points 2+3, I can give up point 3, so I won't be able to continue playback where I left it, but it will ff me back again to the latest moment.